# Нет доступа к id через дефис

Tags: javascript

Почему доступ к id через дефис не работает?
Как это пофиксить?

```js
main-second.outerHTML = 'hand';
```

```css
#main{
background: orange; 
}

#main-second {
font-size: 2vmax;   
margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="main-second">
Text
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: А обращаться к элементам по глобальному id это плохая практика уже лет 15

Comment: Я новичек и не знаю.
А как правильно?
Пожалуйста, приведите правильный пример в коде)

Comment: в этой ссылке ничего не сказано про тире в id

Comment: По ссылке есть примеры. Там же можно и на русский переключится: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#example

Comment: там тоже про тире ничего не сказано

Comment: там два примера и я не могу понять, какой из них правильный, чтобы не обращаться к глобальному id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS интерпретирует ваш код, как - из `main` вычесть `second.outerHTML = 'hand';`.

Если всё же есть необходимость в дефисе, то используйте `getElementById()`:

```js
document.getElementById('main-second').outerHTML = 'hand';
```

```css
#main {
  background: orange;
}

#main-second {
  font-size: 2vmax;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="main-second">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ура заработало =)
А человек вверху сказал "А обращаться к элементам по глобальному id это плохая практика уже лет 15 "
Почему это плохая практика?
И как правильно обращаться к элементам?

Comment: @Новичок: очень [подробно и доходчиво](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom).

Comment: а там есть про плохую практику обращения к элементам через глобальную id?

Comment: И есть ли там способы борьбы с этой плохой практикой)?

Comment: @Новичок, вы по ссылке переходили?

Answer (score -1):

Есть правило, что всё, что написано в *CSS* через дефис, в *JS* пишется через `camelCase`. Именно поэтому есть `el.style.backgroundColor` и пр. обращения к свойствам стилей

Comment: А как написать camelCase вместо тире?

Comment: Попробовал написать mainSecond.outerHTML = 'hand';
не работает